# outputting entities in xml source to valid html

Tags: xslt, lxml

I'm trying to transform some xml with content encoded as html entities.  I want to output the entity content as valid html.

The xml is like this ..

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><memo Version="1.0">
<header>
<meta title="==PROGRAMMING=="/>
<meta favourite="false"/>
<meta uuid="85f94ab2-77a8-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
<meta createdTime="1551038092051"/>
</header>
<contents>
<content>&lt;p value="memo2" &gt;=====&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;https://medium.freecodecamp.org/&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;=====&lt;/p&gt;
</content>
</contents>
</memo>
```

I have some xslt as so..

```py
xslt_src = '''
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

     <xsl:template match="/">
       <html>
         <head>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="memo/header/meta"/>
         </head>
         <body>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="memo/contents"/>
         </body>
       </html>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="memo/header/meta">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@title"/>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="memo/contents">
       <div class='content'>
         <xsl:value-of select="content/text()"/>
       </div>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="@title">
       <span id='title'>
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
       </span>
     </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
'''
```

I process it with lxml in Python...

_________________________________________________________________python

```py
from lxml import etree

xslt = etree.XML(xslt_src)
transform = etree.XSLT(xslt)

src = open('simple.xml').read()
xml = etree.XML(str.encode(src))
result = transform(xml)
root = result.getroot()

print('-----------------------out 1')
print(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True).decode('utf-8'))

print('-----------------------out 2')
content = root.xpath('/html/body/div/text()')
print(content[0])
```

==============================================================

`etree.tostring(root)` prints the structured document but leaves the html entities as encoded in the original xml.

-----------------------out 1

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <span id="title">==PROGRAMMING==</span>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="content">&lt;p value="memo2" &gt;=====&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;https://medium.freecodecamp.org/&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;=====&lt;/p&gt;
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

but if I print `root.xpath('/html/body/div/text()')[0]` (the node with the html content) I get what I want...

-----------------------out 2

```html
<p value="memo2" >=====</p><p>https://medium.freecodecamp.org/</p><p>=====</p>
```

=======================================================================

My question is: how can I make etree.tostring(root) replace the html entities with valid html, as is printed when I use the text attribute directly?

Cheers!

bitrat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<xsl:value-of select="content/text()"/>
```

try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="content" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```